# finiteness in étale cohomology (ell-adic sheaves)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X/k$, $k$ separably closed, be a proper variety. Is then $H_{et}^p(X,\mathbf{Z}_\ell(q))$ finitely generated?